# What is the "the anonymous lifetime #1" and how can I define it in the right way?

Tags: rust

I want the `Handler` below to push itself into the list

```
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Handler<'a> {
    list: Rc<RefCell<Vec<&'a mut Handler<'a>>>>
}

impl<'a> Handler<'a> {
    fn new(list: Rc<RefCell<Vec<&'a mut Handler<'a>>>>) -> Self {
        Handler { list: list }
    }

    fn push(&mut self) {
        self.list.borrow_mut().push(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let list = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::new()));

    let mut h1 = Handler::new(list);
    let mut h2 = Handler::new(list);

    h1.push();
    h2.push();

    // Here the list should contain both h1 and h2

}
```

but I faced this error and I cannot find a way to pass it!

```
error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
  --> src/main.rs:15:37
   |
15 |         self.list.borrow_mut().push(self)
   |                                     ^^^^
   |
note: ...the reference is valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 9:1...
  --> src/main.rs:9:1
   |
9  | / impl<'a> Handler<'a> {
10 | |     fn new(list: Rc<RefCell<Vec<&'a mut Handler<'a>>>>) -> Self {
11 | |         Handler { list: list }
12 | |     }
...  |
16 | |     }
17 | | }
   | |_^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 14:5
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 | /     fn push(&mut self) {
15 | |         self.list.borrow_mut().push(self)
16 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

What is the "the anonymous lifetime #1" and how can I define it in the right way? Or even, is my approach correct to this problem in Rust?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the "the anonymous lifetime #1"

"Anonymous" means something without a name. Lifetimes are things associated with references. Where are the references on line 14?

```
fn push(&mut self)
//      ^ here
```

Due to [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision), you don't have to have an explicit lifetime, allowing it to be implicit (and anonymous).

Your code requires that the `Vec` contains `&'a mut Handler<'a>`, but you are trying to put in a `&mut Handler<'a>` — the lifetime of the reference has no known relation to the lifetime `'a`. The error is telling you this is invalid. You can fix *this* error by relating the lifetimes:

```
fn push(&'a mut self)
```

This doesn't fix the entire program, however.

---

Your specific code structure will probably never work the way you want it to. You want to have a list of references to handlers that themselves contain references to handlers and all of these need to have *exactly* the same lifetime. However, you then declare that the list and handlers all live for different durations as they are declared separately.

I don't know why you'd want the structure you show, but if I needed it I'd probably switch to `Rc` for the handlers instead of `&mut`.

Comment: Thank you for information :) I read most of these things but I cannot figure it out how to implement them :D BTW, what do you mean by "I'd probably switch to `Rc` instead of `&mut`"? I have `Rc` in my code!  Do you mean just defining the list as `list: Rc<RefCell<Vec<Handler>>>`? I did that in the first place and ran into this error: "self.list.borrow_mut().push(self)
^^^^ expected struct `Handler`, found mutable reference". Also you mentioned that "they all need to have exactly the same lifetime". Actually I want handlers to have shorter lifetime than the list. Is it possible? Thanks again.

Comment: @hadilq I mean I wouldn't use mutable references (`&mut`), but instead would use `Rc<RefCell<T>>` https://play.integer32.com/?gist=229b0de1f84cdce9ee02cba26bbe30e5&version=nightly